# I have 3 excel formulas that I would like to fill ranges in a spreadsheet with, how can I make sure the cells change with the rows?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

1. `=IF(AND(G2<>100,TODAY()>=H2, TODAY()<=I2), E2, " ")`
2. `=IF(N2=" ", " ",NETWORKDAYS(H2,TODAY()))`
3. `=IF(OR(O2 = " ", O2 <= 0), " ", (O2/N2)*100)`

These are the three formulas, I want to make sure that as they are inserted into the worksheet the cell references will still change to match the rows they are on, as they would in a normal spreadsheet. Any advice would be much appreciated! (To clarify, I need to fill the ranges using VBA as the code I'm using clears the worksheet every time it is run.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use [FormulaR1C1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823188.aspx) property of range object, which uses the "R1C1" notation for range addresses

for instance inserting your first formula in "A1" would be:

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC7<>100,TODAY()>=RC8, TODAY()<=RC9), RC5, "" "")"
```

where the *pure* `R` would assume the current cell row index, while `C7` stands for a *fixed* (not varying with host cell position) 7th column index reference, and so on

Comment: How does this format treat hidden rows? Do I include them in the "counting" across in columns, or does it only look at displayed columns?

Comment: well, just try it! (but I suspect that 8th column will always be 8th column...)

Answer (score 2):

If i have interpreted your question correctly, you need something like the below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub InsertFormula()

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To n
    Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=IF(AND(G2<>100,TODAY()>=H2, TODAY()<=I2), E2, "" "")"
Next i

End Sub
```

replace the 1 in n=... with whichever column has the most rows of data
replace `for i = 1` to whichever row it must begin form

You will notice i have added extra quotations to the end of the formula, this is needed as quotes in a formula in VBA must be enclosed... in more quotes lol

Apply this concept for the other formulas :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think in my context the FormulaR1C1 works better with my code!

Comment: Sure no problem. If you ever need to use such formuals in a dynamic basis then this may be better. If you think this is useful then please do vote up :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of absolute references like `G2` you can use something along

`.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:R[5]C[-2])"`

where `R` and `C` reference the offset from the current cell (positive: right or down, negative: up or left).

Use it in a way similar to this:

```
Dim c
For Each c In Selection
    c.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:R[5]C[-2])"
Next c
```

Answer (score 2):

Relative References are adjusted when you set the formula to range of cells:

```
[A1:B2].Formula = "=C$1"     ' now the formula in B2 will become "=D$1"
```

You can also set multiple formulas at once:

```
Range("K2:M9").Formula = Array("=IF(AND(G2<>100,TODAY()>=H2, TODAY()<=I2), E2, "" "")", _
                               "=IF(N2="" "", "" "",NETWORKDAYS(H2,TODAY()))", _
                               "=IF(OR(O2 = "" "", O2 <= 0), "" "", (O2/N2)*100)" )
```

or if each row has different formula:

```
[A1:Z3] = [{"=1";"=2";"=3"}]
```